# Why can't questions have identical titles and what to do in that scenario?

Tags: discussion

Apologies if this question has been answered before but I couldn't see any results for it.

I just tried to edit this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923382/manosry-with-bootstrap-3#29923382

I'm pretty sure that OP means `Masonry` instead of `Manosry` but when I went to edit the question I received an error tooltip stating that a question with that title already exists.

I was just wondering why this is the case? I appreciate that the question title is effectively the url but why can't the duplicated title have some kind of suffix appended to differentiate between them and make them unique?

Also, when this happens, what is the correct course of action if I want to correct the spelling in the title but can't?

**Update**

The question has now been edited by another user with the new title `Issue with Masonry and Bootstrap 3`, just to avoid confusion if you follow the link.

Comment: That title should be more descriptive either way... Of course the user has an issue... Why else would the user be asking a SO question?

Comment: ...and the tags indicate that it's with Masonry and Bootstrap 3, so this title adds no information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duplicate titles aren't allowed because it forces you to provide a *descriptive* title that actually gives some indication of your specific problem, rather than having tons of questions with the same extremely broad title.  The correct course of action is to come up with a title that is more specific as to what your problem is, so as to distinguish it from the others.

Comment: ... and go edit the title of the other question so it's more specific as well!

Comment: and/or stop duplicates before they even start

Comment: @BenMorris That does happen, but it's not the primary motivation for the feature.  The "related questions" section shown when asking a question is the primary mechanism (when asking a question) for addressing that.