# Identical Titles avoidable with punctuation

Tags: discussion, questions, title

When you ask a [new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and enter the same title as a previously asked question, the following warning appears:

> A question with that title already exists; please be more specific.
>
> [image: Question Already Exists]

The following titles **will trigger** the warning:

- Is this answer appropriate?
- Is this answer appropriate ?
- Is this answer appropriate??

However, there is a possible loophole since the following title **will not** trigger it:

- Is this answer appropriate.?

**Q:** *Should this be addressed programmatically?*

---

**Further Reading**: [Why can't questions have identical titles and what to do in that scenario?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291698/1366033)

Comment: When do you actually say enough is enough?  This could go on forever, whats currently there is good enough.  Sure it could get better, but then people try to circumvent it even more and more.

Comment: You could also name it 'Is this answer apprοpriate?' (using a Greek ['ο'](https://www.google.com/search?q=ο) instead of a Latin 'o').

Comment: It may also disallow legit use cases - when a small piece of code is included in the title.

Comment: Users punctuating titles? Don't make me laugh.

Comment: @boann, Yes, we used to use this hack to prove that [even google cannot find Chuck Norris](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ϲhuck+Nоrrіs) ;-) (Sorry, unrelated comment...)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If someone was really trying to work around it, there are a variety of ways they could do it.  "Is this answer really appropriate?", etc.  I think the way it is set up now works as good as any way for simply reminding the user to pick a unique title.  If the user is trying to circumvent this requirement, there will likely always be ways to do it.

Comment: Blacklists are not very effective, so it's not really worth trying to improve that too much.

Comment: Plus the mods can warn someone if this is something that someone continues to do on a daily basis.

Comment: +1: the goal should not be to enforce the rule, but the poke the asker into picking a unique title that reflects their problem, not something generic.

Comment: @Yakk nice point of view, I'd consider that an answer on its own. But given that point of view, I'd actually want the duplicate check to be more precise to help the asker even better :)