# Are questions with the same title really inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, title

My question is essentially the same as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254233/question-with-the-same-title-exists), but I feel I have a better example to discuss. ([This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291698/why-cant-questions-have-identical-titles-and-what-to-do-in-that-scenario) also touches on the same topic.)

Today I ran into an error I could not find the answer to, so I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975518/incorrect-syntax-near-in-then-clause). I wanted to title it "Incorrect syntax near '='" since that is the error message (shortened—the rest was not informative) I was getting, but it was already being used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141134/incorrect-syntax-near). I opted to add a little more context, but it was not directly relevant to the problem as I had suspected.

In light of the fact that there are error messages with multiple distinct causes, is it really appropriate to disallow questions with the same title?

---

Personally, I'm okay with enforcing distinct titles. I'm really questioning whether the reason for the rule is sound.

Comment: If your question can be described with the same exact title, it's a very good indication that with some thought on your part answers to that question can be applied to your situation. This is not a "please solve my specific syntax issue without regard to whether it applies to anyone else in the future* site. Questions (and answers) are intended to be of use to many people in the future; if your particular problem can be solved along the way, that's a fortunate side benefit.

Comment: Sorry Ken White, but the question that has the desired title has net -3 and is simply not applicable.

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't describe a sufficiently different problem, see my previous comment. The question score isn't relevant to the question you asked here - if the problem can be described *with the exact same title*, it's most likely a duplicate. Clearly, if it's a different problem, you should be able to come up with a more descriptive title. The reason is 100% sound; having 1000 questions saying "C code doesn't work" or "SQL problem" has zero benefit to people searching for a solution to their problem in the future.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, questions with exactly the same title are inappropriate. 90% of people arrive at Stack Overflow through a Google search. When you type a question in to Google, do you want to see a page with ten links that all have exactly the same title, or do you want to see titles that are more specific so you can quickly find the solution you're looking for? Just write a more specific title to your question.

See also: [Regex Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+problem)

Comment: More specific, as I said in the post, is erroneous.

Comment: See [SQL Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+problem)

Comment: @ricksmt That doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 7):

If two questions have the same title, there are only two possibilities:

1. They are duplicates. Congratulations, you've already found the answer without asking.
2. At least one, and probably both, can be edited to be more descriptive. Edit to describe the actual circumstances and problem, rather than a generic message.

Comment: Possibility 1 is out: the existing question isn't applicable. I used possibility two, and my title became less concise; What right have I to change the other's title?

Comment: There is no rule that a title has to be concise.  And anyone is allowed to edit any post, that's pretty much a main feature of the site.  If it improves the post, do it.

Comment: @ricksmt Coming up with decent title should not be hard if you tried to search for answer first - clearly you've used some words to make search more specific and related to your post - just get all those words into a sentence and you got good title...